# write on windows, compile on mac

Tags: xcode, windows, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Developing for Mac OS X, on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288330/developing-for-mac-os-x-on-windows)

my situation is this, i do not have a mac, but need to write an app for a mac in xcode.

is there a way to write and simulate the code in Windows, save the project on a usb drive, and then compile the final package ona friend's mac when everything is OK?

thanks  igor

ps: the project MUST be xcode compatible, so any other application with other coding languages is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not own a mac, then you can try installing mac osx on your intel based PC, with vmware. However you will not attain all the features, but your xcode will run.

Second thing you can do is, share your friends mac os by Team Viewer, but he should not be using at same time.

Comment: thanks for your answer, already tried the virtual machine, but it is too slow.. thats why i asked for a native windows app..

Comment: you can use few linux based tools, but eventually you will miss the taste of mac. Why dont you purchase mac mini it will cost u around a pc. and you can use or existing monitor, ups, keyboard, mouse....